# Чтение входящего потока в Rust

Tags: linux, rust, pipelines

(поправте меня, если не так сформулирован заголовок)

Как обработать  `stdin` для всех строк в Rust на *nix?

Примеры:

```
~$ cat file | rust_cmd # и что то делаем дальше
~$ rust_cmd < file
~$ xargs -I% rust_cmd % < file
```

Код из документации выдает только первую строку

```
use std::io;

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut input = String::new();

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut input)?;

    println!("You typed: {}", input.trim());
    Ok(())
}
```

Пока сам начал читать в этом направлении, прошу указать на часть в документации, где это описывается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use std::io::{stdin, BufRead};

fn main() {
    let stdin = stdin();
    for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
        println!("{:?}", line);
    }
}
```

Тут `line` будет типа `Result<String, io::Error>`, так что для реального использования содержимого как строки его потребуется "вытащить" через unwrap/expect/match/?/т.п.

Документация ключевых методов:

- https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdin.html#method.lock
- https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю вариант с макросами для тех, кто пришел сюда за ответом про stdin в Rust

```
use std::io;

// defines a macro for reading inputs to a given buffer
macro_rules! scanline {
    ($x:expr) => {
       io::stdin().read_line(&mut $x).unwrap();
    };
}

fn main() {
    let mut input = String::new();
    scanline!(input);
    println!("{:?}",input);
}
```

**Ссылки**

- [Why doesn't Rust have an easy-to-use stdin like C++ does?](https://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-Rust-have-an-easy-to-use-stdin-like-C++-does)